# Accessing openwhisk playground UI in docker-compose deployment

Tags: docker-compose, openwhisk

I am new to openwhisk. I have first done deployment locally in standalone mode. That worked fine. I was able to set `auth` and `apihost` and access the function playground UI via `http://172.17.0.1:3232`. But now I am using docker-compose deployment https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-devtools/tree/master/docker-compose. I have successfully deployed it, all the containers are up and running. I can access kafka topic UI, minio/login, able to create actions via wsk cli. Now I'm not sure whether it provides the configuration for the function playground UI or not. I have tried accessing it but 3232 is not listening or even present. It isn't included in the ports that are exposed.

- 80, 443, 9000, 9001, and 9090 for the API Gateway
- 6379 for Redis
- 2181 for Zookeeper
- 5984 for CouchDB 8085
- 9333 for OpenWhisk's Invoker
- 8888, 9222 for OpenWhisk's Controller
- 9092 for Kafka
- 8001 for Kafka Topics UI

Does that means, it doesn't provide functionality of UI? If it does, how can we access the playground UI via docker-compose deployment? Secondly, this is `generated-conf.d` file. If Api gateway provides the functionality of playground UI, on this endpoint `location /`, which url to use let it proxy_pass to playground UI?

```
upstream whisk_controller {
  server whisk.controller:8888;
  keepalive 16;
}

server {
  listen 443 default ssl;

  ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  10m;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/openwhisk-server-cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/openwhisk-server-key.pem;
  ssl_verify_client off;
  ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";

  client_max_body_size 50m;     # allow bigger functions to be deployed

  location /docs {
    proxy_pass http://whisk_controller;
  }
 location /api-docs {
    proxy_pass http://whisk_controller;
  }

  location /api/v1 {
    proxy_pass http://whisk_controller;
    proxy_read_timeout 70s; # 60+10 additional seconds to allow controller to terminate request
  }

  location /blackbox.tar.gz {
    return 301 https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-runtime-docker/releases/download/sdk%400.1.0/blackbox-0.1.0.tar.gz;
  }

}
```

because this accessing `<ip-address>:80` returns this and I have read somewhere it should lead us to plaground UI.

```
Welcome to API Gateway !
An NGINX and Openresty based API Gateway.
If you see this page, the API Gateway is successfully installed and working. Further configuration may be required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org, openresty.org
```